# How do I program input that can be number or words (C++)

Tags: c++

So, let's just say I'm making a trivia game. I want to be able to make something that can answer:

```
cout<<"What is the most radioactive commonly-eaten fruit?"       

cin>>Answer
```

and can also answer numerical questions like:

```
cout<<"How many days does it take for Earth to orbit the Sun?"

cin>>Answer
```

From there, I can program if statements to handle the rest, but string, double, and int don't let me do answer in order to get there.

Comment: Use `std::string Answer;` as primary input.

Comment: And then use `std::stoi()` and `std::stod()`, or a `std::istringstream`, if you need the answer in `int` or `double` format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this kind of quiz you could probably use `std::string` for everything. In this case you need to store your answers as `std::string` as well and then just compare the strings. For [example](https://ideone.com/IFet0A), and this is a very simple example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

int main()
{
    std::string answer;
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> qas = 
    {
        { "What is the most radioactive commonly-eaten fruit?", "banana"},
        { "How many days does it take for Earth to orbit the Sun?", "365"}
    };

    for (auto &&q : qas)
    {
        std::cout << q.first << " ";
        std::cin >> answer;
        std::transform(answer.begin(), answer.end(), answer.begin(), [](unsigned char c) -> unsigned char { return std::tolower(c); });
        std::cout << ((answer == q.second) ? "Correct!" : "Incorrect!") << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You may want to store the answers in lower case as well as to `std::transform` user answer to lower case for string comparison. However, if for some reason you need to have a numerical value of the answer, you can still read string and then convert it to a number with a few available library functions.

Comment: Can you please explain, what this line does? `std::transform(answer.begin(), answer.end(), answer.begin(), [](unsigned char c) -> unsigned char { return std::tolower(c); });`

Comment: @kiner_shah It transforms user answer string to lower case, just added this to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Answer` as a string, and then you can make the necessary conversions to extract the value you want. For example:

```
include<string
...
std::string Answer;
std::cout<<"What is the most radioactive commonly-eaten fruit?";
std::cin>>Answer;

std::cout<<"How many days does it take for Earth to orbit the Sun?";
std::cin>>Answer;
// So you can use `std::stoi` to convert the value of `Answer` to integer
// Or you can use `std::stod` to convert the value of `Answer` to double
if(std::stoi(Answer) == some_value)
    std::cout<<"You are correct ...";
else
    std::cout<<"Error!";
```

For more, please visit the [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/) site for [stoi](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoi/) and [stod](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stod/). Hope it helps.

Answer (score -2):

You can use "union" or "struct" depending on the input type you want. If you want user to be able to answer with different options then **union** is the way to go.

If you want user to fill more than one information then **struct** is the way to go.

Please follow the link for an example:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union

Comment: Using `union` for this is a horrible idea. Don't mix types unless you absolutely have to (for example in hardware I/O). This particular scenario does **not** varant the use of a `union`